# 'include'-ing a module, but still can't call the method

Tags: ruby, include, require

Why does the following code give the error below?

```
require 'open3'

module Hosts
  def read
    include Open3
    popen3("cat /etc/hosts") do |i,o,e,w|
      puts o.read
    end
  end
end

Hosts.read
#=> undefined method `popen3' for Hosts:Class (NoMethodError)
```

It works if I call `popen3` using full path ie `Open3::popen3`.  But I've `include`-ed it, so thought I wouldn't need the `Open3::` bit?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined an instance method, but are trying to use it as singleton method. To make what you want possible, you also have to `extend` the `Open3`, not `include`:

```
module Hosts
  extend Open3

  def read
    popen3("cat /etc/hosts") do |i,o,e,w|
      puts o.read
    end
  end
  module_function :read # makes it available for Hosts
end
```

Now:

```
Hosts.read
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
=> nil
```

Reading about the following concepts in Ruby will make things much clearer for you:

- context
- `self`
- `include` vs `extend`

Instead of `module_fuction` you could also achieve the same result with either of below:

```
module Hosts
  extend Open3
  extend self

  def read
    popen3("cat /etc/hosts") do |i,o,e,w|
      puts o.read
    end
  end
end
```

And

```
module Hosts
  extend Open3

  def self.read
    popen3("cat /etc/hosts") do |i,o,e,w|
      puts o.read
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: ah, i was thinking along those lines but coming up short. I shall read up on 'extend'. And 'module_function'! Thanks very much.

Comment: @spoovy N/p :) You could also achieve the same effect with few more options. Will edit in a moment (just in case you're interested :))